# Lucene.NET Faceted Search

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, faceted-search, content-indexing

I am building a faceted search with Lucene.NET, not using Solr. I want to get a list of navigation items within the current query. I just want to make sure I'm pointed in the right direction. I've got an idea in mind that will work, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do this.

My plan at the moment is to create hiarchry of all available filters, then walk through the list using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754560/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-this-getcardinality-method-is-doing) to get a count for each, excluding filters which produce zero results. Does that sound alright, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finished my implementation. I did a lot of digging in the Lucene and Solr source code in the process and I'd recommend not using the implementation described in the linked question for several reasons. Not the least of which is that it relies on a depreciated method. It is needlessly clever; just writing your own collector will get you faster code that uses less RAM.

Answer (score 1):

yeah.   you're missing solr.  the math they used behind doing faceted searching is very impressive, there is almost no good reason to not use it.  the only exception i can find is if your index is small enough you can roll your own theory behind it, otherwise, its a good idea to stand on their shoulders.

Comment: "not using Solr" This is a .NET application, it already has Lucene.NET indexing + searching. I'm just trying to add faceted navigation. Seems like using a shotgun to swat a fly to me.