# Is BitOperations.PopCount the best way to compute the BitArray cardinality in .NET?

Tags: .net

`Numerics.BitOperations.PopCount` in .NET is the fastest way I am aware of counting the number of bits set that compose an int. However, I haven't seen anyone using it to compute the number of bits set in a `System.Collections.BitArray` object (example: [Counting bits set in a .Net BitArray Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063178/counting-bits-set-in-a-net-bitarray-class)).

Using the following C++ code as example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  bitset<500000000> visited;
  long limit = 500000000;
  for (long x=0; x < limit; x++) {
    visited[x] = true;
  }
  cout << visited.count() << endl;
}
```

*Running time: 0.36 real  0.34 user  0.02 sys*

Here is my best attempt in F#:

```
open System
open System.Numerics

let limit = 500000000
let visited = Collections.BitArray(limit)
for x in 0..limit-1 do
    visited.[x] <- true
let ints = Array.create ((visited.Count >>> 5) + 1) 0u
visited.CopyTo(ints, 0)
ints
|> Array.map BitOperations.PopCount
|> Array.reduce Operators.(+) 
|> printfn "%d"
```

*Running time: 1.53 real  1.47 user   0.06 sys*

Is it possible to improve the .NET version to match better the C++ implementation?

**UPDATE**

Comparing only to the count part and changing high level functions with a `for` loop increases the gap from C++ being 4x faster to be 5x faster.

```
open System
open System.Numerics
let limit = 500000000
let visited = Collections.BitArray(limit)
visited.[9999999] <- true

let ints = Array.create ((visited.Count >>> 5) + 1) 0u
visited.CopyTo(ints, 0)
let mutable total = 0
for i in ints do
    total <- Operators.(+) total (BitOperations.PopCount(i)) 
printfn "%d" total
```

*Running time: 0.21 real  0.15 user  0.06 sys*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  bitset<500000000> visited;
  visited[9999999] = true;
  cout << visited.count() << endl;
}
```

*Running time: 0.04 real  0.02 user   0.02 sys*

**UPDATE 2**

Replacing `BitArray` with an `uint32 array` improves the performance from 5x to 4x slower than C++ bitset:

```
open System.Numerics
let limit = 500000000 >>> 5
let visited = Array.create (limit + 1) 0u
visited.[9999999] <- uint 0b00100000
let mutable total = 0
for i in visited do
    total <- Operators.(+) total (BitOperations.PopCount(i)) 
printfn "%d" total
```

*Running time: 0.15 real  0.12 user  0.03 sys*

Comment: `System.Collections.BitArray` is **extremely old**.  It's from [.Net 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=netframework-1.1).  It doesn't even implement `IEnumerable<bool>`.  But what times are you comparing exactly?  The performance of `visited.count()` vs `ints |> Array.map BitOperations.PopCount |> Array.reduce Operators.(+) `?  Or the performance of the entire program?

Comment: Take a look at https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/, https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/21/benchmarking-mistakes-part-two/ and https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/09/benchmarking-mistakes-part-three/ to make sure you're comparing apples to apples.

Comment: And I hate to say it, but you really should compare the time of `visited.count()` to the time taken by a simple `for` loop without any delegates or lambdas, to get an idea where the time is being taken.

Comment: Thank you @dbc, I have updated the question to include your recommendations to focus only on `visited.count()` vs `BitOperations.PopCount` but now the gap is even bigger between C++ and .NET. Do you think that could be related to `System.Collections.BitArray` being so old? I tried with an array of bools but that was even slower, so I am not sure what could be a replacement

Comment: Does it have to be specifically a `System.Collections.BitArray` (which you need to copy the data out of, or use Reflection to cheat, both of which have significant overhead), or any kind of bit array (eg `ulong[]` with some functions to treat it as a bit array)

Comment: @nicomp It doesn't have to be a `BitArray`, `ulong[]` sounds like a good option to try

Comment: @nicomp I have updated the question with your idea. This is the fastest version so far so feel free to create an answer and I will be happy to accept it

Answer (score 2):

Under the restriction of having to use a BitArray, `BitOperations.PopCount` seems to be the best alternative:

```
open System
open System.Numerics

let limit = 500000000
let bitArray = Collections.BitArray(limit)
bitArray.[9999999] <- true

let ints = Array.create ((bitArray.Count >>> 5) + 1) 0u
bitArray.CopyTo(ints, 0)
ints
|> Array.sumBy BitOperations.PopCount
|> printfn "%d"
```

*Running time: 0.20 real   0.15 user  0.05 sys*

From there, the next step is to replace the `BitArray` with
`uint[]` as @nicomp indicated.